# Make both of Form and ModelForm can inherit fields from a FormMixin

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I have a `LocationMixin` , it adds a location selector to a form, as below.

```
class LocationMixin(object):
    location_required = False
    location_label = u'location'
    location_text = forms.CharField(label=u'location', required=False, \
                                    widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={
                                        'class': 'city_input  inputFocus proCityQueryAll proCitySelAll',
                                        'autocomplete': 'off',
                                        'readonly': 'readonly',
                                    }))

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(LocationMixin, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if 'location' not in self.fields:
            raise Exception('LocationMixin need form contain field named location !')
        self.fields['location_text'].required = self.location_required
        self.fields['location_text'].label = self.location_label



class ActivateProfileForm(LocationMixin, forms.ModelForm):

    location_required = True

    class Meta:
        model = Member
        fields = ['address', 'car_type', 'car_no', 'location', 'city']
        widgets = {
            'location': HiddenInput(),
            'city': HiddenInput(),
        }
```

But it would be broken at this line:`

> self.fields['location_text'].required = self.location_required

Django complain that `location_text` do not exist in `self.fields`:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 112, in get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "D:\Incubations\Project\xxx\src\xxx\decorator.py", line 54, in wrapper
    return func(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\Incubations\Project\xxx\src\xxx\views_member.py", line 166, in activate_profile
    form = ActivateProfileForm(instance=member)
  File "D:\Incubations\Project\xxx\src\location_selector\forms.py", line 25, in __init__
    self.fields['location_text'].required = self.location_required
KeyError: 'location_text'
```

I have to change `class LocationMixin(object):` to `class LocationMixin(forms.ModelForm):` to make it work, which `class LocationMixin(forms.BaseForm)` can't.

The problem is:
 
I also want `LocationMixin` works with `class SomeForm(LocationMixin, forms.Form)`.

Comment: Will you please provide full traceback?

Answer (score 0):

Your LocationMixin is not really a Django form right now. Try inheriting from `forms.Form` instead of object.

Also, depending on what your goal is, you may need to reverse the order of your main class definition. This:

```
class ActivateProfileForm(LocationMixin, forms.ModelForm):
```

is different than:

```
class ActivateProfileForm(forms.ModelForm, LocationMixin):
```